# Sql join two tables with another that has no common column

Tags: mysql, join

I have this subquery where I am getting the posts of users that a user is following. This is the subquery.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Posts` WHERE UserID IN
    (
    SELECT Followed FROM `Follow` WHERE Follower = ?
    )
    ORDER BY PostDate DESC
    ";

// on bind_param ? will be $userID
```

This works fine but I also want to get the user's own posts and then data from a profiles table so I'm probably going to ditch the subquery for some sort of join. I've used inner joins before however the profile/posts table have a common id 'UserID' but the `Follow` table does not. Would a full join work or would I have to use an AS ?

Comment: isn't followed from follow table a common id with ID from Posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `union` might be best.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE UserID = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT P.* 
FROM posts P
INNER JOIN follow F ON F.followed = P.UserID
WHERE F.follower = ?
```